# Need help determining why I'm getting an error in the console with AM Charts 4

Tags: amcharts

So I just downloaded the latest version of AM Charts. I updated my build script with the core and chart files (I did have to rename core to amcharts.core.js but it seems to work.)

I built my code and the the chart displays. Its just a simple bar chart with hardcoded data but it works. Thats fine.

When I look at my console however I see loads of errors at the same place:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

It is from this section of code

```
"undefined" != typeof MutationObserver) {
        var r = new MutationObserver(function(t) {
            for (var e in t)
                for (var i = t[e].addedNodes, r = 0; r < i.length; r++)
                    i[r].resizeSensor && n.reset(i[r])
        }
        );
```

Its all minified and theres no previous step in the stack trace. Can anyone tell me about this section of the code? What is it? Any ideas on possible causes for the all the errors I see? They come up before the code is even called to do the drawing.

Comment: Could you provide a simplified setup where this can be reproduced? Codepen? Github repo/gist files? Random stack traces are kind of hard to troubleshoot without a repro case, as you can imagine, and renaming vendor files definitely raises a ton of red flags.

Comment: Figured it would be awkward but was kind of hoping that maybe it was an issue seen before. I made a simple test with one of the examples that comes with v4. I changed the name of the file and updated the tags in the html to point to that, but im not getting the same error. For the full picture we build our code into a zip that is then uploaded onto a Salesforce server and run from there, in case that would have any bearing?

Comment: Possibly, but it's hard to say. How are you building this anyway? Is the Salesforce server doing anything else outside of (presumably) unzipping your zip file after you upload it?

Comment: It sounds like you're not building amCharts via npm, rather you're downloading it and including it as part of your build, i.e. concatenating v4 files as part of your own. That would explain why you had to rename core.js to amcharts.core.js, because it has to load first before charts/maps, and a glob include would find it first that way (otherwise charts.js would load first and things would break). So... that much is evident. If everything works before you put it on Salesforce, it does sound like something is happening afterwards...

Comment: Yes that is exactly how I am building it. Sorry, I dont know npm. What is the preferred method of building?

Comment: @discodowney Well it was just confusing is all, when one says "build" what comes to mind is amCharts as a package. Whatever works for you, though, is what's best imo. Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No, not yet. Was off for Christmas and been fixing other things that were actually causing problems. Im gonna have to look at this though in the coming weeks